# How to retrieve large data from web service to Android without outofmemory?

Tags: android, xml, json, web-services

I need to get large amount of data (say 7000 records) from online database to Android application. While searching the web, I came to know that large amount of data will leads to outofmemory problem in json while convert from string. The solution was to convert the json with the help of gson or jackson. I have two question as follows

1. Another solution for converting json to avoid out of memory problem.
2. Shall I get the data in xml format? If so whether I can solve out of memory?

### Edit

```
    String  result = convertStreamToString(is);

  JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); // Only i am getting outofMemory Exception..


   private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int n = 0;
    try {
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buffer))) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
    return out.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: create a POJO class and add the data using JSON. I don't think that JSON will create an out of memory in that case.

Comment: 7000 records with how many columns? I prefer JSON over XML for data transfer because easy conversion to objects. In terms of data load, both XML and JSON takes almost same memory.

Comment: @thinksteep With nearly 15 columns.

Comment: @LalitPoptani can you please explain briefly about POJO class or please refer any url for reference.

Comment: @deepa just a getter setter class to store the downloaded data of JSON.

Comment: but for that first you need to store response as string in some variable. then you can parse this string and stored in POJO class(that is getter setter methods).

Comment: @HirenDabhi how can i store get the value for getter and setter method from string? Since in the string i am having entire 7000 records if i need single records i have to use json only. while converting from string to json only iam getting outofmemory issue.

Comment: @deepa yes i am asking the same thing, to stored the records on database first u have to get those data and then insert into database or POJO class. this comment is for LalitPoptani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think xml format will allow you for large amount of data. I am developing a Project where I download approx 15000 data in xml and there is no a memory issue.

Comment: While displaying 7000 records in listview of my android application, whether i will get memoryissue here?

Comment: I am not sure about that dear, but if your device is enough capable of execute that load of memory piece then it will not fire that error.

Comment: I've 45000 records how should i go

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Jackson`, since it's a streaming processor, you can directly feed in an arbitrarily sized `InputStream` to the `ObjectMapper.readValue()` method. As long as the records themselves are not too heavy, then you should be able to keep them in memory. That said, you should probably not keep them in memory, you should feed them into a database and query them from there.

Comment: i am getting outofmemory error while converting string into json object. Is Jackson solve my error?

Comment: I don't know how you are "converting a string into a json object", so it's hard to tell why you're running out of memory. However, Jackson shouldn't run out of memory while converting from JSON into Java.

Comment: Perhaps JSONObject is not meant for that. Definitely give Jackson a try.